# Finding concave areas to enclose in a 2D grid for an AI agent

Tags: algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array, graph-algorithm

For a game that's similar to Qix, Volfied, Paper.io and splix.io, where you need to encircle an area to capture it, I'm struggling to find proper way for AI to detect valuable territory features to capture.

The image below presents 9 examples of territory fragments of a bigger map, where the blue color is territory owned, black color is empty area that need to be captured, green  and white points need to be calculated, so AI could pass through them to actually capture territory.

This can also be formulated as: how to find shortest path that encircles as much of empty area as possible?

Maybe a contour tracing algorithm could be used??

[image: Examples of situations needed to be discovered]

Comment: The naive solution would be: From each border pixel (of the already filled area + playground border) shot a ray in each possible moving direction (away from the filled pixels). When it hits another filled pixel calculate the filled area and the path length. For the intermediate stop you also have to shoot a ray from each pixel of the first ray. Then choose the best (path, area) tuple according to a weighting function. Do you think this would be too slow?

Comment: @SaiBot Nice solution, but I believe it would be very CPU-intensive, as to calculate an area I would need to do a flood fill which would result in dozens of flood fills of so many possibilities. But I'll think about that, because it is intuitive and maybe there is a method to optimize this approach.

Comment: Don't think of it as a flat playfield; think of it as a list of areas that have not yet been captured, each of which contain their bounding points.  When you create a new area, given that it knows its bounds, it knows its size.  Maintain this area list sorted by size, and always pick the top.  Then your question becomes: "given one area with a limited number of vertices, what's the best way to divide it to get most area for smallest cutting distance?"  That probably does involve ray casting each vertex, but it's a single closed polygon, so it should be optimizable.